# Simple Rails form accepting data but flashing that it's not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms

Hi guys I am very stuck at the moment, my form seems to be accepting data, refreshing, but not saving it into the database as it still flashes "Entry not saved" when clicking save. Also when checking the console, there is no data saved that was just filled in. I'm not sure where the problem lies. Here is what I have:

Controller:

```
class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @submissions = Submission.all
end

def new
    @submission = Submission.new
end

def create
    @submission = Submission.new(params[:submission])
    if @submission.save
        redirect_to("/submissions/new")
        flash[:alert] = "Entry saved."
        
    else
        redirect_to("/submissions/new")
        flash[:alert] = "Entry not saved."
    end
end

def update 
end

def submission_params
    params.require(:submission).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :content)
  end
```

end

Model:

```
class Submission < ApplicationRecord
validates :content, {presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}}
validates :first_name, {presence: true}
validates :last_name, {presence: true}
validates :email, {presence: true}
end
```

New.html.erb:

```
<%= form_with model: @submissions do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

  <%= f.label :last_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Logs:

```
Started GET "/submissions/new" for ::1 at 2020-11-26 14:50:42 +0100
Processing by SubmissionsController#new as HTML
Rendering submissions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered submissions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 11.6ms | Allocations: 4519)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 84ms (Views: 82.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 11939)
```

Routes:

```
root to: 'home#index'
get "riders/index" => "riders#index"
get "submissions/index" => "submissions#index"
get "submissions/new" => "submissions#new"
post "submissions/new" => "submissions#create"
get "home/location" => "home#location"
get "photos/index" => "photos#index"
```

I'm quite new to Rails so any help will be appreciated. I've spent hours looking for the answer and nothing so far.

Comment: `@submission = Submission.new(submission_params)`
    `if @submission.save!`

Comment: I tried this, but still no luck. It's not refreshing now either, no flash message. This is what I got from the logs: ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: submission):
app/controllers/submissions_controller.rb:27 :in `submission_params'
app/controllers/submissions_controller.rb:12: in `create'  any idea why this may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller#create action you need to change the line:

```rb
@submission = Submission.new(params[:submission])
```

to:

```rb
@submission = Submission.new(submission_params)
```

Now the logs tells you that the param submission is missing or the value is empty. This is because in your controller#new you got:

```rb
@submission = Submission.new
```

But in your form you got @submissionS. So in order to fix the errors/problems change the form to @submission without the s at the end.

Comment: thanks for your answer, still having issues. I'm now getting a NoMethodError: undefined method `submissions_path' Did you mean?  submissions_new_path. So does that mean some issue with the routing?

Comment: Ahh yes I see in your routes you got post "submissions/new" change that to "submissions" without the /new

Comment: holy moly that worked! It was so simple, thank you so much